# OpenAPI Schema - Put Request into S3 turns binary file (.doc/.pdf) into empty json file

Tags: json, swagger, openapi, gpt-4

I am working on a custom GPT 4 application within chatGPT and in the configure tab there is a place where you can implement some OpenAPI schemas.

I am trying to simply make a PUT request to move an uploaded file (.pdf) into an S3 bucket.

I successfully connect to the API but when I look in S3, the file is either empty or has some small amount of info about the document inside.

i.e.

> {"metadata": {"name": "Manual", "description": "A comprehensive manual for Capri, including important contact numbers,  other information, instructions, recommendations, and FAQs."}, "fileData": "/mnt/data/test.pdf"}

Can someone please help me understand if what I am trying to do is possible and how I may do that? I tried the API in POSTMAN and the response was 200 and the file was in its original format.

I tried postman and it worked fine;
as soon as I try to bring it into OpenAPI schema, I lose....

Here is my schema code:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "S3 Bucket File Management API",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://HIDDEN.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/bnb-bucket-ham/{filename}": {
      "put": {
        "summary": "Upload a file to the S3 bucket",
        "operationId": "uploadFile",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "metadata": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": ["name"]
                  },
                  "fileData": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "byte"
                  }
                },
                "required": ["metadata", "fileData"]
              }
            },
            "application/pdf": {},
            "application/msword": {},
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": {}
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "File uploaded successfully"
          }
        }
      },
      "get": {
        "summary": "Retrieve a file from the S3 bucket",
        "operationId": "getFile",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "filename",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "File retrieved successfully",
            "content": {
              "application/pdf": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "binary"
                }
              },
              "application/msword": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "binary"
                }
              },
              "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "binary"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "File not found"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the request body look like?  if you are uploading the file from a UI it should be multipart/form-data. It is possible to send the file over the network without form-data, but not very common. You are only showing the `responses` but you need to indicate the `requestBody` schema is `content-type: application/pdf` so the server understands you are sending a pdf file. The response is not needed, just return a 202 Accepted with an empty body.  see this answer for a similar question I just answered today. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504777/8564731

Comment: @JeremyFiel, he's having a similar issue i think to me. He's also making an openai customgpt action and trying to send a user file to another server. I think whatever the answer is it is an openai specific thing and not necessarily a problem with openapi configuration.

Comment: Hamoun, did you figure it out? I'm still stuck

Comment: @JeremyFiel - thank you for your response. I will try on your advice and let you know. I am using ChatGPT4 which only has a UI for the schema. I will post here and tag you both once I try again!

Comment: @Philip7899 - no, but lets both keep each other updated it we do!

Comment: @JeremyFiel

The requestBody is set to accept multipart/form-data.
Within multipart/form-data, a file property is defined, which is expected to contain the binary content of the file.
The response for a successful upload is now 202 Accepted with an empty body, indicating that the request has been accepted for processing.

it still didn't work...